# Using a static pointer to a class memory mangement?

Tags: c++, memory, static, vector, copy-constructor

I have a class for stars in my game, I want them to use the same texture so I've come up with this code...

```
sf::Texture* Star::starTexture = NULL;
unsigned int Star::refCount = 0;

Star::Star() : starSpeed(0), starScale(0), locX(0), locY(0)
{
    if (starTexture == NULL)
    {
        starTexture = new sf::Texture();
    }

    refCount++;
}

Star::~Star()
{
    refCount--;

    if (refCount == 0)
    {
        delete starTexture;
        starTexture = NULL;
    }
}
```

I'm using the star class like this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < STAR_COUNT; ++i)
{
    Star star;

    star.Initialize(/* blah blah */);

    starVector.push_back(star);
}
```

I'm new to "advanced c++ techniques" and I'm worried this isn't going to work. Do I need to define a copy constructor? will the vector mess up my reference count? I'm open to suggestions for a better way to do this too. I guess I could keep the texture outside the class and pass a reference when I initialize each star but I perfer the texture staying inside the class...

Comment: Why add compilcations of refcount. Why not sf::Texture Star::starTexture; Let the stack tack the strain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it'll mess up if you don't explicitly define `copy constructor` and `copy assignment operator` for you class.

STL containers like `vector` have **copy-by-value** semantics. When `Star` object is copied into a `vector`, the raw pointer inside it is copied. So you now have multiple pointers pointing to a single memory, which definitely puts you on the fast track to undefined behavior, at best.

What you should do, is to define those functions explicitly. Manually perform the **deep copy** of that memory and increment your ref count properly.

A better way is to hold an RAII-object like `boost::shared_ptr` or `std::tr1::shared_ptr` inside your class and let it handle resource management(including ref-counting stuff) automatically for you. Then you don't need explicitly define those functions anymore.

```
class Star
{
..
private:
  std::tr1::shared_ptr<sf::Texture> m_starTexture;
};

// link the smart pointer w/ resource
Star::Star(): m_starTexture(new Texture())
{
  ...  
}
```

This is guaranteed to work by language features:

1. *When your object is copied, copying functions of non-static member objects are called*.
2. *When your object is deleted, destructors of non-static member objects are called*.

In this case, copying functions of smart pointer will correctly increment ref count while 
destructor of it will decrement ref count, and deallocate the resource if ref count equals 0.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a little confused with std::tr1::shared_ptr though, will every instance of Class star have access to the same texture or will each new star create a new texture? can I declare a static shared_ptr in the header?

Comment: That depends. When you creates a new star object, it creates a new texture in its constructor. So if you create 10 start objects(either on stack or on heap), they have 10 different textures inside. However, when you copy a star object, e.g., to a vector or to another star object, those objects share the same texture. Don't use static for shared_ptr.

Comment: You probably need to figure out how smart pointers works usually. It's powerful. Just google it.)

Comment: Thanks again, I'm going to look into it.